# Redis MSOpenTech : max memory "OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory'" error even though RDB file after save is only 3 GB

Tags: memory, memory-management, redis

The redis server version I use is 2.8.9 from MSOpenTech github. Can anyone shed light on why redis "info" command indicates that used memory is 21 GB even though the RDB file that's saved on disk is < than 4 GB? I did successfully run a "save" command before noting down the size of the RDB file. The qfork heapfile is 30 Gb as it's been configured in redis.windows.conf.

Configuration :

maxheap 30gb
max-memory 20 Gb
appendonly no
save 18000 1

The server has 192 GB of physical RAM, but unfortunately only has about 60 GB of free disk space and I had to set max-heap and max-memory to 30 Gb and 20 Gb respectively so that I have additional space to persist the data on disk.

I'm using redis as a cache and the save interval is large as seeding the data takes a long time and I don't want constant writing to file. Once seeding is done, the DB is updated with newer data once a day.

My questions are :

1. How is the saved RDB file so small? Is it solely due to compression (rdbcompression yes)? If yes, can the same compression mechanism be used to store data in memory too? I make use of lists extensively.
2. Before I ran the "save" command, the working set and private bytes in process-explorer was very small. Is there a way I can breakdown memory usage by datastructure? For example : List uses x amount, Hash uses y amount etc?
3. Is there any way I can store the AOF file ( I turned off AOF and use RDB because the AOF files were filling up disk space fast ) in a network path ( shared drive or NAS )? I tried setting the dir config to \someip\some folder but the service failed to start with the message "Cant CHDIR to location"

I'm unable to post images, but this is what process-explorer has to say about the redis-server instance :

1. Virtual Memory:

   - Private Bytes : 72,920 K
   - Peak Private Bytes : 31,546,092 K
   - Virtual Size : 31,558,356 K
   - Page faults : 12,479,550
2. Physical Memory:

   - Working Set : 26,871,240 K
   - WS Private : 63,260 K
   - WS Shareable : 26,807,980 K
   - WS Shared : 3,580 K
   - Peak Working Set : 27,011,488 K

The latest saved dump.rdb is 3.81 GB and the heap file is 30 GB.

```
# Server
redis_version:2.8.9
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:1fe181ad2447fe38
redis_mode:standalone
os:Windows  
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:winsock_IOCP
gcc_version:0.0.0
process_id:12772
run_id:553f2b4665edd206e632b7040aa76c0b76083f4d
tcp_port:6379
uptime_in_seconds:24087
uptime_in_days:0
hz:50
lru_clock:14825512
config_file:D:\RedisService/redis.windows.conf

# Clients
connected_clients:2
client_longest_output_list:0
client_biggest_input_buf:0
blocked_clients:0

# Memory
used_memory:21484921736
used_memory_human:20.01G
used_memory_rss:21484870536
used_memory_peak:21487283360
used_memory_peak_human:20.01G
used_memory_lua:3156992
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.00
mem_allocator:dlmalloc-2.8

# Persistence
loading:0
rdb_changes_since_last_save:0
rdb_bgsave_in_progress:0
rdb_last_save_time:1407328559
rdb_last_bgsave_status:ok
rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec:1407328560
rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec:-1
aof_enabled:0
aof_rewrite_in_progress:0
aof_rewrite_scheduled:0
aof_last_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_current_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_last_bgrewrite_status:ok
aof_last_write_status:ok

# Stats
total_connections_received:9486
total_commands_processed:241141370
instantaneous_ops_per_sec:0
rejected_connections:0
sync_full:0
sync_partial_ok:0
sync_partial_err:0
expired_keys:0
evicted_keys:0
keyspace_hits:30143
keyspace_misses:81
pubsub_channels:0
pubsub_patterns:0
latest_fork_usec:1341134
```

Comment: What is the value of `maxmemory` in configuration?
You may check it with `CONFIG GET maxmemory`.